# How to prove that$\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{1+\sin\left(x\right)} = \frac{1-\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How can I prove that:$$\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{1+\sin\left(x\right)} =  \frac{1-\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}$$

My attempt:

$$\cos^2(x/2) =\frac{\cos x +1}{2}$$
$$\sin x = 2 \sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$$

$$\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{1+\sin\left(x\right)} =\frac{2\cos^2(x/2) -1}{1+2 \sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}=  \frac{(\sqrt2\cos(x/2) -1)\sqrt2\cos(x/2) +1)}{1+2 \sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}$$ 
Can anyone help me to simply this last expression or provide me with tip?

Comment: $$\frac ab =\frac cd\iff ad=bc$$

Comment: Have you tried cross-multiplying?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern thanks That was blatantly obvious I did not think about that.

Comment: @Math_QED Even though I did not see that before, I dn't see how It can a duplicate the functions are diferents

Comment: Cross multiplying isn't the "cleanest" way to prove an identity. When you cross multiply, you assume the equation is true. I think the answer provided by Mc Govern is the way. Work on ONE side of the equal sign  and arrive at the other. Another method would be on the left hand side to multiply top and bottom by $cosx$ and go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying the $\mathrm{LHS}$ by the conjugate of the denominator:

$$\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{1+\sin\left(x\right)}\cdot\frac{1-\sin\left(x\right)}{1-\sin\left(x\right)}$$

$$\frac{\cos\left(x\right)\left(1-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{1-\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}$$

Using the the Pythagorean identity:

$$\frac{\cos\left(x\right)\left(1-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{\cos^{2}\left(x\right)}$$

Canceling $\cos(x)$:

$$\frac{1-\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}$$

Answer (score 4):

It's 
$$\cos^2x=(1-\sin{x})(1+\sin{x})$$ or 
$$\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$$  or
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

it is $$\cos(x)^2=1-\sin(x)^2$$ by cross multiplication